# Объединение запросов, UNION

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Есть 2 sql запроса:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tratingsumm INNER JOIN iezl2_users ON `tratingsumm`.`ID_Driver` = `iezl2_users`.`id` INNER JOIN trating ON `tratingsumm`.`ID_RatingSumm` = `trating`.`ID_Driver`  WHERE `trating`.`ID_Pass`='".$iddr."' ORDER BY `tratingsumm`.`ID_RatingSumm` ") or die (mysql_error());

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tratingsumm INNER JOIN iezl2_users ON `tratingsumm`.`ID_Driver` = `iezl2_users`.`id` WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM trating WHERE `trating`.`ID_Driver` = `tratingsumm`.`ID_RatingSumm` AND `trating`.`ID_Pass` = '".$iddr."') ORDER BY `tratingsumm`.`ID_RatingSumm`") or die (mysql_error());
```

При попытки объединения их через оператор UNION, пропадает подсветка синтаксиса и выдается ошибка. По отдельности каждый из запросов работает корректно. Пример - первый запрос выдает данные с id 1 и 3, второй с id 2 и 4, и идет поочередный вывод результатов запросов в порядке 1, 3, 2, 4. А объединение мне нужно, чтобы сделать общий ORDER BY на результаты объединенного запроса и добиться вывода 1, 2, 3, 4. Возможно ли их вообще объединить таким способом?

Comment: а не left join ли вы пытаетесь изобрести?

Comment: Поясните, как можно добиться такого результата с помощью left join. У меня при попытке его применения результаты вывода были некорректны.

Comment: LEFT JOIN точно должен помочь. только не забудьте условие `trating.ID_Pass = $iddr` перенести в ON. Если оно останется в where, то оно уничтожит эффект от LEFT

Comment: Не работает такая запись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изобрести вы ясно пытаетесь `left join` вот такого вида:

```
SELECT * FROM tratingsumm 
INNER JOIN iezl2_users ON `tratingsumm`.`ID_Driver` = `iezl2_users`.`id` 
left join trating ON `trating`.`ID_Driver` = `tratingsumm`.`ID_RatingSumm` 
        AND `trating`.`ID_Pass` = '".$iddr."'
ORDER BY `tratingsumm`.`ID_RatingSumm`
```

---

`union` же (или куда вероятнее подразумевался `union all`) собрать тоже можно. Необходимо учитывать, чтобы все элементы результата были совместимой структуру - у вас из-за дополнительного `join` в первом запросе `select *` явно выдаёт разное число полей. И второй момент с сортировкой - её необходимо указать так, чтобы парсер понял, что сортировать надо результат union, а не последний запрос. В общем виде так:

```
(select ...)
union all
(select ...)
order by ...
```

Comment: Спасибо вам! У меня, видимо, была опечатка где-то в коде, ваш left join сработал.